# MongoDB Group/match on sum

Tags: mongodb

I have the following aggregator:

```
db.user.aggregate([{ $match : { type : "follow" } },
                        {$group:{_id: { $month: "$createdDate" }, 
                        follow:{$sum:1}} } ]);
```

And gives the output of:

```
{
    "_id" : 9,
    "follow" : 36
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "follow" : 12
}
```

However I need to add another statement so the output looks like

```
{
    "_id" : 9,
    "follow" : 36,
    "unfollow" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "follow" : 12,
    "unfollow" : 3
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Where does the value of `unfollow` come from?

Comment: $match : { type : "unfollow"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline step to evaluate the counts based on the `type` value, something like the following:

```
db.userRating.aggregate([    
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": { "$month": "$createdDate" },             
            "follow": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "follow" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "unfollow": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "unfollow" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }
        }  
    }
]);
```